# PHP-Websocket: Problems with socket_recv() and socket_getpeername()

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I'm using PHP Websocket and sometimes, I get the following both warnings.
 
Warning-1:

> socket_recv(): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Warning-2:

> socket_getpeername(): unable to retrieve peer name [107]: Transport endpoint is not connected

I send messages to the Websocket by another PHP-Script. This PHP-Script sends a message and if it's finised, the Socket-Call ends. 
So this Warning is probably correct, because the "endpoint" (= the PHP-Script) is no loger connected.
But this Warning is not beautiful..
So this is the following Code for Websocket, which is received the messages:

```
define('HOST_NAME',$host_ip); 
define('PORT',$socket_port);

$null = NULL;

$socketHandler = new SocketHandler();

$socketResource = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socketResource, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socketResource, 0, PORT);
socket_listen($socketResource);

$clientSocketArray = array($socketResource);
while (true) {

    $newSocketArray = $clientSocketArray;
    socket_select($newSocketArray, $null, $null, 0, 10);

    if (in_array($socketResource, $newSocketArray)) {
        $newSocket = socket_accept($socketResource);
        $clientSocketArray[] = $newSocket;

        $header = socket_read($newSocket, 1024);
        $socketHandler->doHandshake($header, $newSocket, HOST_NAME, PORT);

        socket_getpeername($newSocket, $client_ip_address);

        $newSocketIndex = array_search($socketResource, $newSocketArray);
        unset($newSocketArray[$newSocketIndex]);
    }
    foreach ($newSocketArray as $newSocketArrayResource) {  
    while(socket_recv($newSocketArrayResource, $socketData, 1024, 0) >= 1){

            $socketMessage = $socketHandler->unseal($socketData);
            $messageObj = json_decode($socketMessage);

            break 2;
        }
        $socketData = @socket_read($newSocketArrayResource, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);

        if ($socketData === false) { 
            socket_getpeername($newSocketArrayResource, $client_ip_address);
            $newSocketIndex = array_search($newSocketArrayResource, $clientSocketArray);
            unset($clientSocketArray[$newSocketIndex]);         
        }
    }
}
socket_close($socketResource);
```

The command, which produces the Warning-1

> socket_recv(): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

is:

> while(socket_recv($newSocketArrayResource, $socketData, 1024, 0) >= 1)

In the [PHP-Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recv.php)  there is mentioned to get the return-value of socket_recv(). But in the examples there is only shown to execute socket_recv() once, by using if(). 
But I use socket_recv() within the loop-header. 
So my question: 
**How do I check return-value in my case - by using socket_recv() within a loop-header?**

Warning-2

> socket_getpeername(): unable to retrieve peer name [107]: Transport endpoint is not connected

was produced with the following code:

> socket_getpeername($newSocketArrayResource, $client_ip_address);

My question is:
**What have I to do in order not to execute socket_getpeername(), if the client is no longer connected?**

Maybe someone can help me to fix these Warnings. It's very difficult do watch, because these Warings do not always appear..

Bye,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

> How do I check return-value in my case - by using socket_recv() within a loop-header?

you can capture the return value of socket_recv and check it's value, but it's important that you do it in the correct order, and you can dictate in which order php does it, by using ()'s, eg:

```
while(($bytes_recieved=socket_recv($newSocketArrayResource, $socketData, 1024, 0)) >= 1)
{
   // now you can check it inside the loop, it's $bytes_recieved
}
// you can also check it outside the loop, it's still in $bytes_recieved
```

(however, note, if you place the ()'s wrong, it will instead become the bool result of >=, for example, this is wrong: `while($bytes_recieved=(socket_recv($newSocketArrayResource, $socketData, 1024, 0) >= 1))` , with this, $bytes_recieved would instead become the bool result of `>=`.)

> What have I to do in order not to execute socket_getpeername(), if the client is no longer connected?

well, if you apply the above patch, i think you can check if $bytes_recieved is true-ish, eg

```
    if (!!$bytes_recieved) { 
        socket_getpeername($newSocketArrayResource, $client_ip_address);
        $newSocketIndex = array_search($newSocketArrayResource, $clientSocketArray);
        unset($clientSocketArray[$newSocketIndex]);         
    }
```

- doing `!!` will convert it to bool(true-ish), and  it's probably true-ish if the client is still connected, and probably false-ish otherwise. - although, this may get a false positive if the client didn't send anything any bytes a while, so it might be safer to check if it's directly false instead of false-ish, which you can check by using `===`, eg

  ```
  if ($bytes_recieved === false) { 
      socket_getpeername($newSocketArrayResource, $client_ip_address);
      $newSocketIndex = array_search($newSocketArrayResource, $clientSocketArray);
      unset($clientSocketArray[$newSocketIndex]);         
  }
  ```

... btw, i don't know for sure, but it looks like your code here just randomly selects a client sharing $newSocketArrayResource 's ip address, instead of choosing $newSocketArrayResource specifically. if your server never receive more than 1 connection per ip address, i guess this is OK (still a shitty design choice, imo, but not directly bugged), but i think you should select clients by the resource id, rather than the ip address, then your server would be able to support more than 1 connection per ip address. i think you should set the key to the resource id, and instead do:

```
    if ($bytes_recieved === false) { 
        unset($clientSocketArray[(int)$newSocketArrayResource]);
    }
```

... and lastly, looks like you have a resource leak here, just unsetting it will leave you with memory leaks (and handle leaks), i think you want:

```
    if ($bytes_recieved === false) {
        unset($clientSocketArray[(int)$newSocketArrayResource]);
        socket_close($clientSocketArray);
    }
```

that will leave you without memory/handle leaks.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried your example with "while(($bytes_recieved=socket_recv..)", but Warning already appears: "PHP Warning:  socket_recv(): unable to read from socket [10053]: Socket Error 10053 - An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine". So in order to get the return-value for $bytes_recieved, socket_recv() has to be executeed first for return-value. I think I have to check first, if the client is still connected and if it is so, I can call socket_recv(). But I don't know what I have to check before executing socket_recv. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Funkfeuer are you asking `how to get the return value of socket_recv and hide the warning message` ?  in which case, the answer is  `while(($bytes_recieved=@socket_recv($newSocketArrayResource, $socketData, 1024, 0)) >= 1)`

Comment: Yes, you're right. By using while(($bytes_recieved=@socket_recv($newSocketArrayResource, $socketData, 1024, 0)) >= 1) I get the return_value, but the Warning still appears with it. What could I do that socket_recv() doesn't produces the Warning?

Comment: @Funkfeuer if the warning still appears, then set `xdebug.scream` to `0`  in php.ini - or teach your custom set_error_handler() function to check the active error_reporting() level before throwing warnings around. `if (!(error_reporting() & $severity)) {/*ignored because of error_reporting level*/ return;}`

Comment: xdebug says: `PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\socket_server.php:0
PHP   2. socket_recv() C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\socket_server.php:67
Warning: socket_recv(): unable to read from socket [10053]: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
 in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\socket_server.php on line 67
Call Stack:
    0.0004     392096   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\socket_server.php:0
   77.2232     503704   2. socket_recv() C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\socket_server.php:67`.

Comment: @Funkfeuer and you used `@` with socket_recv ?  then you still have not disabled `xdebug.scream`  in php.ini